# AWK in search programme

Tags: awk

does anyone know the meaning of this code

```
search_book()
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$1" '$1 ~ search || $2 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' books.txt
}
```

what does this mean? Thank you

`search="$1" '$1 ~ search || $2 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }`

Comment: Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins. That book will answer this and all future awk questions for you.

Answer (score 1):

Some info

```
awk -F':' -v search="$1" '                              # Splite the indata by ":" , get the pattern to search from  "$1" in the bash       
$1 ~ search || $2 ~ search {                            # If field "#1" or "#2" does contain the search pattern do:
    i++                                                 # Increment variable "i"
    printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }   # and print field $1 to $5
```

This `{printf "%s, %s,$%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }` can be change to
`{print $1," "$2,"$"$3,$4,$5}' OFS=,`